# De un SELECT FORM escoger una figura y pintarla en la misma página sin redireccionar a ninguna otra

Tags: html, select, canvas

Necesito saber como de un select escoger una figura y que me la pinte en la misma página. En este caso la página se llama index.html pues que al darle click en submit me la pinte en la misma página. Solo tengo el rectangulo de momento pero tendría que hacerlo con todas. 
El CODIGO que tengo es:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
            <title>
                Figuras Geométricas
            </title>
            <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js">
                    </script>
                    <script src="js/main.js">
                    </script>
                </link>
            </link>
        </meta>
    </meta>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.html">
        <select name="Figuras">
            <option value="Rectangulo">
                Rectángulo
                <canvas height="600" id="Rectangulo" width="600">
                </canvas>
                <script>
                    var miLienzo = document.getElementById("Rectangulo");
                    var lapiz = miLienzo.getContext("2d");
                    lapiz.strokeRect(5,5,200,100);
                </script>
            </option>
            <option value="Circulo">
                Círculo
            </option>
            <option value="Triangulo">
                Triángulo
            </option>
            <option value="Cuadrado">
                Cuadrado
            </option>
            <option value="Pentagono">
                Pentágono
            </option>
            <option value="Hexagono">
                Hexágono
            </option>
            <option value="Octagono">
                Octágono
            </option>
            <option value="Cubo">
                Cubo
            </option>
            <option value="Esfera">
                Esfera
            </option>
            <option value="Cono">
                Cono
            </option>
            <option value="Piramide">
                Pirámide
            </option>
            <option value="Cilindro">
                Cilindro
            </option>
        </select>
        <br>
            <br>
                <input type="submit">
                </input>
            </br>
        </br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para ponerle un color de fondo a las figuras, puedes usar `fillStyle = color`. Por otro lado las figuras con googlearlas salen todas. Si tienes algun problema con alguna en especifico te ayudamos. Pero si lo puedes hacer tú, intentalo primero.

Comment: El problema esta en que como es un formulario osea de un select en vez de ir a otro archivo .php cuando se seleccione la figura se quede en el index.html con la figura dibujada

Comment: No queda nada claro lo que intentas hacer. Si quieres pintar las figuras en tu canvas al cambiar las opciones en el select no te hace falta hacer ningún submit. Símplemente añadir un evento onchange a tu select y llamar en ese evento a una función que te pinte la figura seleccionada (pásale como parámetro el value de la option seleccionada y así sabes el tipo de figura)

Comment: @Kiko_L eso quiero justo, como le paso el parametro del value de la opcion seleccionada?

Comment: Ahora te pongo una respuesta

Comment: Es eso justo sisi tenía que haber hecho mejor mi pregunta. Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varias cosas a tener en cuenta respecto a tu código original:

1. Estabas creando el `canvas` dentro de las `option` del `select`. Lo he sacado.
2. El `script` que estabas ejecutando dentro del `option` también lo he sacado a una función nueva.
3. Los `tags` `br` no se cierran en una linea aparte. Se ponen sólos (como `<br/>` o como `<br>`)

```js
 

//Document ready. Esto se ejecuta tras cargar el DOM de la página

$(function(){
 $("#Figuras").on("change",function(){
        //En el evento "change" del select llamamos a pintarFigura con el valor de la 
        //option seleccionada como parámetro
  pintarFigura($(this).val());
 });
});

function pintarFigura(figura){ 
 
 //Borramos el canvas
 clearCanvas();

 let miLienzo = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 let lapiz = miLienzo.getContext("2d");
 
 if(figura === "Rectangulo")
 {
  lapiz.strokeRect(5,5,200,100);
 }
 else if(figura === "Circulo")
 {
  lapiz.beginPath();
  lapiz.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
  lapiz.stroke();
 }
 else if(figura === "Octagono")
 {
  lapiz.strokeStyle = "#000000";
  lapiz.lineWidth = 1;   
  let numberOfSides = 8,
  size = 100,
  Xcenter = 100,
  Ycenter = 100;
  lapiz.beginPath();
  lapiz.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          
  for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfSides; i += 1) 
  {
   lapiz.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
  }
  lapiz.stroke();
 }
 ///... El resto de figuras (en internet puedes encontrar cómo hacer cada una. Las 3D son bastante, bastante más complejas (a no ser que recurras a librerías externas como d3.js)
}

function clearCanvas(){
 let miLienzo = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 let lapiz = miLienzo.getContext("2d");
 
 lapiz.clearRect(0, 0, miLienzo.width, miLienzo.height);
 lapiz.beginPath();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
            <title>
                Figuras Geométricas
            </title>
                <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    </script>
                </link>
            </link>
        </meta>
    </meta>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.html">
        <select id="Figuras">
            <option value="Rectangulo">
   Rectángulo                               
            </option>
            <option value="Circulo">
                Círculo
            </option>
            <option value="Triangulo">
                Triángulo
            </option>
            <option value="Cuadrado">
                Cuadrado
            </option>
            <option value="Pentagono">
                Pentágono
            </option>
            <option value="Hexagono">
                Hexágono
            </option>
            <option value="Octagono">
                Octágono
            </option>
            <option value="Cubo">
                Cubo
            </option>
            <option value="Esfera">
                Esfera
            </option>
            <option value="Cono">
                Cono
            </option>
            <option value="Piramide">
                Pirámide
            </option>
            <option value="Cilindro">
                Cilindro
            </option>
        </select>
   <canvas height="600" id="myCanvas" width="600" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
                </canvas>
        <br/>
            <br/>
                <input type="submit">
                </input>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: la parte de las funciones esta en un archivo js aparte entiendo no?

Comment: Perfecto ya lo tengo operativo ahora faltaría ordenar un poco ya que visualmente queda feo ejjeje pero si pregunta respondida!